# Perfect Pitch vs Relative Pitch, which is Considered Better

Tags: absolute-pitch, relative-pitch

I have a question here about Perfect and Relative pitch.

So basically, my friends have been arguing about which of Perfect and Relative pitch is better, but I cannot decide.

Perfect Pitch can make you sing or play an instrument in tune, and also can make you tell notes with different pitches apart - even things like F#4 and F semisharp 4.

Relative Pitch is quite different, it is like knowing what a chord is, but not knowing the key if you do not have Perfect Pitch (or in some cases, you do recognise the key but you do not have Perfect Pitch).

So could someone please help me and tell me which type is better and more useful to the majority of people, as in whole communities? Thank you! (Note: I think I have both, but I am not exactly sure about the relative pitch)

Comment: This is probably a dupe. Aaron..?

Comment: I disagree that perfect pitch means you sing in tune.  It just means that when you hear an "A", you say "that's an A".  That has nothing to do with whether that's A440 or A435 or somewhere in between.  And even if an "A" was A440, what good is know that what an A440 is when the band is tuned to A435?

Comment: One is necessarily a subset of the other - If you have Perfect Pitch, you must also have Relative Pitch.  If you can tell exactly what 2 notes are, you by definition know how far apart they are.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Technically yes, but like if you don't know theory, that's just painful.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman As someone who has absolute pitch (also known as perfect pitch) but not relative pitch, I disagree with you completely.  I can't tell what an interval is, other than by calculating - that is, I hear a C and an E, and I can calculate that they're a major third apart, but I can't recognise an interval of a major third without calculating.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - absolutely not.

Comment: @Tim I don't think it's a dup (surprisingly), but I do think it's highly unlikely to be answered with anything other than opinions, speculation, and anecdotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, I disagree that possessing perfect (absolute) pitch 'can make you sing or play an instrument in tune'. That pre-supposes you can actually sing, or play that instrument well, and may even hinder that, if it's not tuned perfectly.

Absolute pitch is often described as a mixed blessing - both being able to identify pitches and suffering when a well-known piece is played in a different key - so I'm told. It's possibly more of a party piece than useful in a musical setting, although it comes in useful when tuning an instrument - but - how accurate to you want that A note to be - 440 or 435Hz?

Relative pitch is possessed by probably a majority of musos - that being >50%. It's far more useful, and even if one doesn't realise one possesses it, it will be apparent when singing or playing the same piece in different keys. So, a great asset to have as a muso.

So, the two are very different, even though they're sort of, but not very, related. And, although it's opinion - disliked on this site - absolute pitch comes second.

Answer (score 7):

This topic is often very difficult because of terms that have vague or conflicting definitions, and a certain amount of misinformation or myth. I would recommend you throw out your working definitions and start from scratch.

- All of these skills are basically about "identifying things." "Perfect pitch" (also called [absolute pitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_pitch)) is about hearing a single note and being able to say that it's, say, an A, or possibly being able to sing an A without anyone giving you a note to hear first. "Relative pitch" is about identifying intervals, or the distances between notes. It means someone might play you an A and a D, and you would say, "I have no idea what those notes are, but they're a fifth apart." Or that, perhaps, someone could play you a note, and you could then sing that note plus another a fifth away, without knowing what their names are.
- These skills exist in a continuum. If we use the superhero ability of flight as an analogy, then some can soar through space like Superman or Captain Marvel, some can fly short distances if you give them a boost first, and some can hover a few feet in the air for a few seconds. They're all part of the same conversation. Some people *can* tell the difference between A 440 and 441 (I mean, I guess they can; I don't personally know anyone who really could with accuracy); others can just tell that a note is closer to being an A than a B. Some might identify intervals with 75% accuracy, or have trouble with fourths and fifths.
- Importantly to your point, the ability to identify and the ability to recreate can be separate. You could maybe *tell* that an A is an A but still not be able to sing in tune. You might be able to identify a major 7th but not sing it accurately. The skills are related, of course, but not guaranteed to go hand-in-hand.
- *There is a certain degree of learning or acquisition involved with all these skills*. They are often talked about in a pseudoscientific, rather superstitious way, as if they are X-Men-style mutations, bestowed by fate, that presage marvelous musical abilities. "The kid sang a note in tune! He has perfect pitch! Quick, get him music lessons!" "Nature vs nurture" questions are terribly hard to research. Yes, there is some evidence that some of these abilities can be innate. But no one ever came out of the womb knowing that a note was A 440 Hz—because they have no idea yet what "A" means. You might recognize thirds and fifths without yet knowing their names, just as a toddler might distinguish between red and green, but will later learn to talk about scarlet, magenta, kelly green, and forest green.
- These skills can also be "acquired" through regular and prolonged musical activity. If you listen to a certain song every day for years, and especially if you sing along with it, eventually your ear and your larynx will get familiar enough with the starting note that you can probably imagine or sing it with reasonable accuracy. If you live with thirds and fifths and sevenths, hearing them and playing or singing them while thinking about them and knowing them by name, you will increase your ability to recognize them.

So which is most useful? Well, relative pitch means that you can hear the contours of a melody and the way this note relates to the previous note and the next one. That's pretty important. Meanwhile, absolute pitch sort of "contains" relative pitch. If I can tell that this note is a G and the previous one was a C, then of course I can also tell you that the interval was a fifth. It's hard to imagine having absolute pitch with no awareness of relative pitch ("I can work out that it's a fifth, but I have no 'feeling' for the fifthiness of it"). If that situation could be imagined, it could be fairly useless; naming pitches, after all, is of little value in performance; it's a party trick. But barring some kind of brain injury, it's hard to imagine spending much time with intervals, knowing their labels, and not acquiring some degree of relative pitch.

Meanwhile, one is seldom asked to produce a pitch without the benefit of a reference pitch. Relative pitch can help you through the task of transcription as long as you can have a piano at hand. No acapella choir is expected to start singing without hearing a pitch pipe first, and then you can calculate your starting pitch by interval from it.

So ultimately, "which is more useful" is an unwinnable argument, especially as they rarely exist in pure, separate, and perfect forms.

Comment: I've read about the case multiple times on this website of the person with absolute pitch whose relative pitch is so poor that they no longer recognize a song after someone transposes it to a different key.

Comment: Andy Boomer, what would you say? What degree of absolute pitch do you possess?

Comment: @StefanH As a violinist, I've acquired some degree of absolute pitch, but especially within violin range; I can't identify notes lower than violin range as accurately. I have trouble with certain timbres; I can identify piano or flute pitches quite easily, but saxophone or human voice with less accuracy. I might be able to sing a named pitch without a reference note, but maybe like 60% reliability. In the process of the years of music-making that led to this pitch recognition, I've also developed relative pitch; even if I'm unable to identify the absolute pitch, I can always identify intervals

Comment: @StefanH And I certainly am not a "human tuner" that can tell the difference between 440 and 441 Hz. (In fact, I sometimes get confused since I spend a lot of time playing baroque music at 415, one half step lower, so that I spend all day associating "A" with what sounds like A flat at modern concert pitch; sometimes I can come out of that a little miscalibrated.)

Comment: @StefanH Lol I cannot identify notes below Bb0, because like, that is Way too low :(.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I am not good at this stuff, but I also noticed that identifiying notes, or playing tunes by ear, is way easier for me for guitar pieces (I play guitar). PS: By identifying notes I do not mean that I can name them instantly, but that it does not take long to find them on the fretboard with an "trial and error"-approach.

Comment: @StefanH That's a different skill, really, "pitch-matching." But an important one: "Playing in tune" (or singing in tune) is really just pitch-matching with a high degree of precision. As you compare the sound you're making to the reference sound you hear, the first question is "Are they the same," then "am I higher or lower," then "by a lot, or a little"? All these are learned skills—sometimes you find people who have no idea whether a pitch is higher or lower than another. Eventually you associate "a lot" or "a little" with more precise terms—a seventh, a half step.